# Proving that $f$ is not continuous

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I was trying the following exercise on continuity :

$$
f(x,y,z)=
\begin{cases}  \frac{\sin xy}{x^2+y^2+z^2} & \text{if $(x,y,z)\neq (0,0,0)$} \\ 0 & \text{if $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$} \end{cases} $$

And I tried to prove that  $f(x,y,z)$ is continuous in $(0,0,0)$ by proving this inequality holds for all $\epsilon \gt 0$ : $$ \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2} \lt \delta  \Rightarrow |\ f(x,y,z) | \lt \epsilon$$

This I did very elegantly like so :
$$ \bigg\vert\frac{\sin xy}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\bigg\vert \le  \bigg\vert\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\bigg\vert \le \bigg\vert\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\bigg\vert = \epsilon$$

Then I said choose $\delta := \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ .
Now my course notes contradicts this, and it says the function is not continuous at $(0,0,0)$. My question is (as I assume I'm wrong) where is the flaw in my thinking ? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the chain of inequalities you are using the fact that $w\geq \sqrt{w}$ for $w\geq 0$ which is not true in general (false for $0<w<1$ for example).

To see that the function is not continuous at $0$ we can approach $(0,0,0)$ in two different ways and get two different limits. First put $x=y=0$ and $z=t$ and let $t\to 0$. Then 
$$
\lim_{t\to 0} f(0,0,t)=0
$$
since $\sin 0=0$ and now put $x=y=t$ and let $t\to 0$ to note that
$$
\lim_{t\to 0} f(t,t,t)=\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{\sin(t^2)}{3t^2}=\frac{1}{3}.
$$

Comment: Clear answer, thank you.